# Position all selected vertices to the same place

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

Can I position all selected vertices to the same place?

I basically want to set all of their x positions to 0.

Comment: Not sure, it's more a question about how to position several vertices at a (same) given position (not just align on an axis). Am I right, @Petah?

Comment: @Polosson I believe the OP was asking how to align vertices on the X axis. "I basically want to set all of their x positions to 0".

Answer (score 33):

Just found an answer from: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?167457-Transform-multiple-vertices-flatten-snap-to

> There are two methods that I usually use
>
> 1. select the vertices and press <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> to put all the vertices in the same z-position, then move then set the 'Median Z'
>      value in the transform properties.
> 2. put the cursor in the wanted z-position, select the wanted vertices and set pivot to 3d cursor, then press  <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>

Comment: second method is nice

Comment: first method is less destructive, does not have secondary effects. second method changes pivot point.

Answer (score 7):

In *Edit Mode* select the vertices and use [scaling](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transformations/Basics/Scale) <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd> to constrain it to the x-axis, after that you can numerically input the scaling value (in your case zero) <kbd>0</kbd>, confirm with <kbd>enter</kbd> or <kbd>LMB</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Or programmatically:

```
import bpy, bmesh

me = bpy.context.object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

for v in bm.verts:
    if v.select:
        v.co.x = 0

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True, False)
```